# Url.Action and Url.RouteUrl renders empty on production box(MVC3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing

I am having a strange issue. The Url.Action and Url.RouteUrl renders correctly in the development server(IIS 7.5, Windows 7) but the same code on production box(dedicated server running IIS 7.5, Win 2008 R2) renders it blank.

The html in my view is :

```
<div style="display:none;">
        <a href='@Url.Action("generateCaptcha", "Home" )' id="generateCaptcha"></a>
        <a href='@Url.Action( "send", "Home" )' id="send"></a>
        <a href='@Url.Action("check_captcha", "Home")' id="check_captcha"></a>
    <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("default", new { action = "generateCaptcha", controller = "Home" })" id="generateCaptcha1"></a>
        <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("default", new { action = "send", controller = "Home" })" id="send1"></a>
        <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("default", new { action = "check_captcha", controller = "Home" })" id="check_captcha1"></a>

    </div>
```

The output in view source is:

```
<div style="display:none;">
<a href='' id="generateCaptcha"></a>
<a href='' id="send"></a>
<a href='' id="check_captcha"></a>
<a href="" id="generateCaptcha1"></a>
<a href="" id="send1"></a>
<a href="" id="check_captcha1"></a>
</div>
```

The difference between dev and prod environment is that on my dev machine mvc4 is installed and on prod box only mvc3 is installed.

I have tried routeDebug on production box. When I browse for home/generateCaptcha the "default" route is selected.

I do not understand why the url.action is not able to generate the correct url only on production box.

While deploying, I have even added the deployable dependencies.

I have the following routes defined:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ByCatSubCat" // Route name
           , url: "browse/{categoryName}/{subcategoryName}/" // URL with parameters
           , defaults: new { controller="Greeting", action="List"} // Parameter defaults
            );

       routes.MapRoute(
           name: "CardDetail" // Route name
          , url: "browse/{categoryName}/{subcategoryName}/card{id}" // URL with parameters
          , defaults: new { controller = "Greeting", action = "Details" } // Parameter defaults
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ByCatSubCatAll" // Route name
           , url: "browse/{categoryName}/{subcategoryName}/" // URL with parameters
           , defaults: new { controller = "Greeting", action = "List", subcategoryName="all" } // Parameter defaults
         );

        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ByCat" // Route name
       , url: "browse/{categoryName}/" // URL with parameters
       , defaults: new { controller = "Greeting", action = "List" } // Parameter defaults

     );

        routes.MapRoute(
             "Default", // Route name
             "{controller}/{action}/{id}/", // URL with parameters
             new { controller = "Greeting", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
         );
```

### Please help.

Update:
It seems that UrlParameter.Optional does not work here.
When I added one more route without having UrlParameter.Optional, all the links started working in production box.

My updated routes are:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ByCatSubCat" // Route name
   , url: "browse/{categoryName}/{subcategoryName}/" // URL with parameters
   , defaults: new { controller = "Greeting", action = "List" } // Parameter defaults
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "CardDetail" // Route name
       , url: "browse/{categoryName}/{subcategoryName}/card{id}" // URL with parameters
       , defaults: new { controller = "Greeting", action = "Details" } // Parameter defaults
     );
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ByCatSubCatAll" // Route name
       , url: "browse/{categoryName}/{subcategoryName}/" // URL with parameters
       , defaults: new { controller = "Greeting", action = "List", subcategoryName = "all" } // Parameter defaults
     );

    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ByCat" // Route name
   , url: "browse/{categoryName}/" // URL with parameters
   , defaults: new { controller = "Greeting", action = "List" } // Parameter defaults

 );
    routes.MapRoute(
                    "Default", // Route name
                    "{controller}/{action}/", // URL with parameters
                    new { controller = "Greeting", action = "List" } // Parameter defaults
                );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default1", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}/", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Greeting", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up an area, for example: Url.Action("Models", "Russian", new { brand = mod.Brand.NameEngShort, area = "Catalog" })